# php var_dump equivelant or print_r

Tags: php, var-dump

since I am using json, and ajax it's annoting I cn't pass the value on a valid json.

is there away to just return the value of var dump without it echo,being output to the browser.

e.g.

```
$data = 'my_data';
get_var_dump($data);//not real func
//should do nothing.
$get['data'] = get_var_dump($data);
$get['error']= false;
echo json_encode($get);
//should be something like 
//{"data,"string(7) my_data","error":false}
```

or the print_r equivalent I just want to to be assigned to a var instead of outputting it.

or if ur a wordpress fan, difference between bloginfo('url'); and get_bloginfo('url'); should make it easier :)

Comment: Are you saying you want to print the values to the screen with out using the echo keyword?

Comment: ok the `var_dump` should be `function var_dump($str){ return $str; }` not `function var_dump($str){ echo $str;}` so that way I can assign it to a varible

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`print_r` has the option for a second parameter.  When set to true, it returns the dump as an array instead of displaying it.

https://www.php.net/print_r

Comment: thats what I was looking for... so used to `print_r` the normal way I didnt even know it exists but thnx :)

Comment: Pedantic note: `print_r` is a very different output to `var_dump`.  Print_r only shows the structures and approximate values (printable value).  `var_dump` actually shows the exact values and structure including the string length.  I personally find no use for `print_r` since `var_dump` has so much extra valuable information...

Answer (score 16):

Sure you can! To do that you will need two PHP buffer functions: [`ob_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [`ob_get_clean`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php). The first one starts buffering, when the second is getting value and cleaning buffer. Example:

```
ob_start();
var_dump($array);
$value = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Dont understand the downvotes. Because `var_export()`, `var_dump()` and `print_r()` have all slightly different formats, this one should at least get mentioned.

Comment: What's wrong with my answer? It is working.. I don't understand why ppl are downvoting ..

Comment: Downvoters: Please note that this is *exactly* how [print_r](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) and [var_export](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) work internally to return instead of outputting.  So if you want the different format of `var_dump` (including types and sizes) this is actually the proper method...

Answer (score 6):

Check the `var_export()` function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

You pass a variable to it and a second boolean parameter, if the second parameter is true the functions return a string with a rapresentation of the variable:

```
<?php
$a = array(1, 2);
$dump = var_export($a, true);

print $dump;
?>
```

`$dump` contains something like

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Everybody has beaten me to it: var_export()

Comment: hhahaha I was looking at that just after my post myself lol +1 tho